# CakePHP - Warnings when looking at the test.php, and nothing loads

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans

I've develped a website using CakePHP, and it works fine on my local machine. After moving everything onto my server, it's now stopped working. I've checked that the server is reading the /var/www/app/webroot/ folder correct, and I've checked that the files it's looking for exist.
I've also given it all the permissions it needs. I'm completly stumped. Any help would be great!

```
Warning: include(/var/www/app/Config/core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 72

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/app/Config/core.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 72

Fatal error: Can't find application core file. Please create /var/www/app/Config/core.php, and make sure it is readable by PHP. in /var/www/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 77
```

I'm using apache2 as a server, and i developed it using the Netbeans CakePHP template.
Cheers!

Comment: The error messages are quite clear - it can't find the files it needs.

Comment: assuming `/var/www/app/Config/core.php` exists, check file permissions.

Comment: Also, if you developed on Windows and moved it to Linux, you might have issues with file upper/lowercases.

Comment: As i said in my post, I've checked the file permissions (For testing purposes, I've given it everything).
Why would the cases have changed if I moved the entire project over?

Comment: The cases wouldn't change, but Windows ignores file case so config = Config, but on Linux that 2 different things.

Comment: I've checked the above, and still not working. I just get the above errors for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Digital Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452108/digital-chris) for pointing me in the right direction. I found that a single folder had a capital where it shouldn't. A fresh pair of eyes this morning helped me spot it.

So moral of the story - Check the file paths thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache files from **app/tmp/persistent/** folder.

If that does not help. Can you tell which version of CakePHP you are using, and also a screenshot of your file structure would help.